# What is the opposite of Cancel?

Tags: vocabulary

I am working with order page, when user press on Cancel Order Button, He should Choice one of the following:

1-cancel order.

2-(opposite of Cancel) order.(this choice Means do not do any thing with order)

What is the opposite of Cancel on this case?
keep in your mind, Cancel is usually what you press to decline an action in a UI situation, and here on my second choice, I am trying to do that.

Comment: *Do not cancel order*.

Comment: If you don't do anything with the order (e.g. save, accept, execute, etc), why do you need to press a button?

Comment: because i need to allow user to have 2 choices >> cancel the order or do not do anything

Comment: It's tricky because Cancel is usually what you press to decline an action in a UI situation.

Comment: @polarysekt  yes

Comment: I'd be tempted to go with, "Proceed" as in proceed to cancel order, and "Return" as in return to order. Or, "Are you sure you want to CANCEL ORDER" - Yes / No. Or a "CANCEL ORDER" / "CONTINUE WITH ORDER" but it would seem misleading.

Comment: @polarysekt..that is what i am doing .. add your answer, it is acceptable to me

Comment: "Continue" or "Proceed".

Comment: @HotLicks The scenario is clicking "Cancel Order", then confirming (or declining). It would make the UI ambiguous if the confirmation buttons are *Cancel* and *Continue/Proceed*. *Cancel* could be taken to mean *Cancel the order* or *Cancel the order cancellation*; and *Proceed* could be taken to mean *Proceed with the order* or *Proceed with the cancellation*.

Comment: This question might be better answered on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [User Experience,](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) not ELU.

Comment: Simply ask *Are you sure?* with the answers being *yes* and *no*. The user already clicked *Cancel Order* button.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd call it *cancel* (to cancel the operation). But since the operation is already called *cancel*, you might want to call it *retain* instead. That is, you want to press that #2 button to retain the order.

> **Retain** *verb*
>   1 Continue to have (something); keep possession of.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retain)

This avoids giving the impression of *accepting* or even *executing* the order, and allows the status quo to remain.

As you note, "Cancel is usually what you press to decline an action in a UI situation". To keep the UI consistent, you may want to rename the operation "Delete Order" or "Retract Order", and keep *cancel* for its usual function.

Answer (score -2):

I guess it should be "Accept Order".

Comment: question updated